# How to get the values on operand stack which the JVM instruction operates on with Javassist?

Tags: java, jvm, javassist

Javassist Provides the [CodeIterator](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/CodeIterator.html) for editing a code attribute, which can be used to transverse all the instructions in the method.

For a JVM instruction, it always follows the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html): 

`mnemonic
operand1
operand2
...`

Different from binary assembly, the stack-based JVM instructions takes value on the operand stack. Take the `ifge` as an example. The instruction has the following format

`if<cond>
branchbyte1
branchbyte2`

ifge succeeds if and only if `value` on stack ≥ 0, the `branchbyte1` and `branchbyte2` are the targets of the jump.

My question is, can I get the `value` on the operand stack using Javassist?

Comment: The specification doesn't say "operand", it says "Operand Stack". The JVM has a stack-based architecture at the specification level, and the "operand" is popped from the stack, where it was previously left by a previous instruction.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks for clarifying. is it right to say "get the values from the Operand Stack used by the instruction"?

Comment: I’d prefer using ASM for the job, but anyway, your question is unclear. There are both, operands and values on a stack, but in either case, you *know* which operands and parameters each instruction has. It’s written in the specification you have linked…

Comment: @Holger, Can you explain why you prefer using ASM for the job?

Comment: Compare [this API](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) with the `CodeIterator`…

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the `javassist.bytecode.analysis` module. According the JVM specification, `frame` is used to store data and partial results. Each frame has its own array of local variables, its own operand stack, and a reference to the run-time const pool.

In `javassist.bytecode.analysis.FramePrinter`, the funciton `print` shows how to print for each frame at each instruction.

```
/**
 * Prints the instructions and the frame states of the given method.
 */
public void print(CtMethod method) {
    stream.println("\n" + getMethodString(method));
    MethodInfo info = method.getMethodInfo2();
    ConstPool pool = info.getConstPool();
    CodeAttribute code = info.getCodeAttribute();
    if (code == null)
        return;

    Frame[] frames;
    try {
        frames = (new Analyzer()).analyze(method.getDeclaringClass(), info);
    } catch (BadBytecode e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    int spacing = String.valueOf(code.getCodeLength()).length();

    CodeIterator iterator = code.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int pos;
        try {
            pos = iterator.next();
        } catch (BadBytecode e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        stream.println(pos + ": " + InstructionPrinter.instructionString(iterator, pos, pool));

        addSpacing(spacing + 3);
        Frame frame = frames[pos];
        if (frame == null) {
            stream.println("--DEAD CODE--");
            continue;
        }
        printStack(frame);

        addSpacing(spacing + 3);
        printLocals(frame);
    }

}
```

From this code, we can see:

The frames can be acquired by `frames = (new Analyzer()).analyze(method.getDeclaringClass(), info);`

**NOTE, this only return the type information of the stack item, but it doesn't give variable names.**

As for the values each instruction uses, we should treat it differently according to the specification of the instruction.